# I need to create query connect 3 tables with Many to Many relationship in MariaDb

Tags: mariadb, query

I have Many to Many relationship Tables.
**items, caregories, stock, item_category, item_stock**

```
Items:                  Categories:         item_category:

╔════════╦════════════╗ ╔═════╦═══════════╗ ╔═════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║item_id ║ item_name  ║ ║  id ║   name    ║ ║  id ║item_id ║category_id║
╠════════╬════════════╣ ╠═════╬═══════════╣ ║  1  ║   1    ║     1     ║
║ 1      ║ Paper      ║ ║  1  ║  office   ║ ║  2  ║   1    ║     2     ║
║ 2      ║ PC Monitor ║ ║  2  ║  school   ║ ║  3  ║   2    ║     3     ║
╚════════╩════════════╝ ║  3  ║    IT     ║ ╚═════╩════════╩═══════════╝
                        ╚═════╩═══════════╝

Stock:              item_stock:
╔════╦════════════╗ ╔════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║    name    ║ ║ id ║ item_id ║ stock_id ║
╠════╬════════════╣ ╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║ 1  ║  stock 1   ║ ║ 1  ║    1    ║    1     ║
║ 2  ║  stock 2   ║ ║ 2  ║    1    ║    2     ║
╚════╩════════════╝ ╚════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

Now, I need to create query for something like this:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║id ║ items.name ║               category                ║                stock                  ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Paper      ║ {"name": "office"},{"name": "school"} ║ {"name": "stock 1},{"name": "stock 2"}║
║ 2 ║ PC Monitor ║ {"name": "IT"}                        ║ {"name": null}                        ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, instead

```
SELECT  i.id,
        i.item_name AS 'item name',
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS 'category',
        GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS stock
    FROM items AS i
    LEFT JOIN ( item_category AS ic ON ic.item_id = i.item_id
           JOIN category AS c ON c.id = ic.category_id )
    LEFT JOIN ( item_stock AS is ON is.item_id = i.item_id
           JOIN stock AS s ON s.id = is.stock_id )
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with some little changes like: **GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT...** and everywhere **LEFT JOIN**